# How to apply/schedule for AD0-E702 Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer Certification?

Tags: magento2, certification

I am not much sure how to schedule AD0-E702 Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer exam ?

I have few questions :

1. Can we take exam on own system ?
2. How it works ?
3. What are prerequisite ?

Thankyou

Comment: Any change in the process guys?

Answer (score 1):

For scheduling an exam, go to `https://www.certmetrics.com/adobe/candidate/exam_scheduling.aspx` then select your exam.

1. You can take the exam online on your computer. Or you can take an offline exam by going to their test center.
2. If you scheduled an online exam, at the scheduled time, you must be online and a proctor will be assigned to you. You will process the exam under the observer of the proctor.
3. You must have some basic knowledge about Magento to pass the exam.

Comment: Thankyou for the information

Comment: Which OS is required in system & is external camera is necessary ?

Comment: Not sure about the OS requirement but I took the exam on a Windows machine. And an external camera is not required, you can use your laptop's built-in webcam.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link to find all the information regarding adobe certified professional exam
https://spark.adobe.com/page/ClHLYMaUjTUfa/
Click on button Schedule your exam
[image: exam schedule]
You will be redirected to
https://www.certmetrics.com/adobe/candidate/exam_scheduling.aspx?%20redir=yes
You will see two option Examity online and Proctored exam with test center online.
[image: exam]